# android imagebutton onclick doesnt change resource

Tags: android, imagebutton

***I want 3 things to change when i click on my imagbutton if boolean is true:***

- backgroundcolor
- set edittext: focusable, clickable
- backgroundresource

**But only the** *backgroundcolor* **is working. The resource doesnt change and the focusable and clickable of the edittext is always false**

```
        editfirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean check;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (check == true){
                editfirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit36px);
                editfirst.setBackgroundColor(0xFF99b6b3);
                editTextfirst.setFocusable(false);
                editTextfirst.setClickable(false);
                check = false;
            }

            else if (check == false){
                editfirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.done36px);
                editfirst.setBackgroundColor(0xFFb2b2b2);
                editTextfirst.setFocusable(true);
                editTextfirst.setClickable(true);
                check = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
editfirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit36px);
editfirst.setBackgroundColor(0xFF99b6b3);
```

This will first set the background to `edith36px` and then replace it again with the color `0xFF99b6b3`.

If you want to change the image on the image button you have to use [setImageResource(int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)).

If you want to disable a view you should use `setEnabled(false)`. I don't think setting clickable to false is working if you have a click listener attached.